# ~./zshrc : command not found: #

Tags: shell, arch-linux, zsh

I have upgraded my system with `sudo pacman -Syu`, then I opened a terminal and saw this.

[image]

Any suggestions, how to fix this issue?

Comment: It is possible you wrote your `~/.zshrc` from a MS Windows editor which added a UTF-8 BOM at the start of the file? You may want to run `LC_ALL=C sed -n l < ~/.zshrc` to help you spot invisible characters in the file.

Comment: You could also try `LC_ALL=C zsh -x ~/.zshrc` to clearly see what it being executed.

Comment: See also [How can I remove the BOM from a UTF-8 file?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/381230)

Comment: MS also adds a carrage-return at the end of lines.

Comment: If the above does not fix then show us the file `~/.zshrc`, or at least the start of it, well at least line 1. And show text as text, images of text can be hard to read, especially by blind people.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks it helped me find out the fault.  

@ctrl-alt-delor ```\357\273\277# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close \
to the top of ~/.zshrc.$```
This is my first line of .zshrc file. So i just need to remove those BOM characters.